# Yii2 + Redis as Database

Tags: database, activerecord, redis, yii2, models

I want to use Yii2 and redis as database.

So far, I got Redis ActiveRecord Class for Yii2 from Here.

[link1](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis)

[link2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-redis-index.html)

but, I got a problem. WHY THIS CLASS ADDS ANYTHING AS HASH IN REDIS????

Above that I cant Find in which pattern it Insert data. I add one user and it will add a user under `user:xxx` namespace and another record under `s:user:xxx` and so on but none of theme has any fields that i defined in attributes!! only contain IDs.

I know that a Key-value type database and RDBMS are different and also know how can implement relation like records in Redis, but I don't know why it will only save IDs.

I could not find any example of using redis ActiveRecords so far.

There is one in here and its not good enough.

So here is my main wuestion: how can add data to redis Using activeRecords and different data types In YII2?

And if its impossible with ActiveRecords what is the best solution? in this case

ANOTHER QUESTION: is it possible to use a Model instead and write my own model::save() method? and what is the best data validation solution at this rate?

Actually I want to make a telegram bot, so i should get messages and send them in RabitMQ and get data in a worker, do the process and save results to Redis, and finally send response to user through the RabitMQ.

So I need to do a lot of validations AND OF COURSE AUTHENTICATIONS and save and select and range and save to sets an lists and this and that ....

I want a good way to make Model or active record or the proper solution to validation, save and retrieve data to Redis and Yii2.

Comment: Please Help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis DB can be declared as a **cache** component or as a **database connection** or **both**.

When it is declared as a **cache** component (*using the [yii/redis/cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-cache.html)*) it is accessible within that component to store *key/value* pairs [as shown here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html).

```
$cache = Yii::$app->cache;

// try retrieving $data from cache
$data = $cache->get($key);
// store $data in cache so that it can be retrieved next time
$cache->set($key, $data);

// one more example:
$access_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
$cache->add(
    // key
    $access_token, 
    // data (can also be an array)
    [
        'id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id
        'name' => Yii::$app->user->identity->name
    ], 
    // expires
    60*60*3
);
```

Also other components may start using it for caching proposes like `session` if configured to do so or like the [yii\web\UrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html) which by default will try to cache the generated URL rules in whatever valid caching mechanism defined under the config file's `cache` component as explained [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$cache-detail). So it is normal to find some stored data other than yours in that case.

When Redis is declared as a **DB connection** like in the links you provided which means using the [yii\redis\Connection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-connection.html) class you can make your model extending its [\yii\redis\ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-activerecord.html) class as any other ActiveRecord model in Yii. The only difference I know so far is that you need to define your attributes manually as there is no DB schema to parse for NoSQL databases. Then just define your rules, scenarios, relations, events, ... as any other ActiveRecord model:

```
class Customer extends \yii\redis\ActiveRecord
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return ['id', 'name', 'address', 'registration_date'];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['name', 'required'],
            ['name', 'string', 'min' => 3, 'max' => 12, 'on' => 'register'],
            ...
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {...}
    ...
}
```

All available methods including `save()`, `validate()`, `getErrors()`, ... could be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-redis-activerecord.html) and should be used like any other ActiveRecord class [as shown in the official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html).

Comment: thanks, so there is no way to set attributes or data types to other things like lists or sets? in predefined methods. can i define my own save method and change its functionality? but then, validation is a problem would it work if i override the save method?

Comment: Yes you can always override the original [save()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L632) inherited from **BaseActiveRecord** inside your model. But you may just need to override lower level methods,to better understand how it works have a look at yii/redis/ActiveRecord [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis/blob/a920547708c4a7091896923abc2499bc8c1c0a3b/ActiveRecord.php). you can always override those methods or introduce a new ones within your model. `$db->executeCommand($command)` is the main function here to communicate with REDIS...

Comment: ...and default [command list can be seen here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis/blob/a920547708c4a7091896923abc2499bc8c1c0a3b/Connection.php#L90)

Comment: also note that default save method will either update or insert a new record. [inside those lower level methods validation is handled](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis/blob/a920547708c4a7091896923abc2499bc8c1c0a3b/ActiveRecord.php#L101). if that method need to be overridden just do the same and every thing should work fine.