# Set data in redis cache in yii2

Tags: caching, model-view-controller, redis, yii2

I have configured redis in my yii2 project. Now, i am performing a query like this(query is working)-

```
$dist = Model::find()->where(['IN','col1',$arr])->all();
```

I've used some functions to set the data in cache but can't figure out whether it's set or not?

After setting or storing data in cache, i will need to access it. How can i store data and later access it when needed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about read documentation? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#multiSet()-detail

Comment: Redis could be used either within an **ActiveRecord** class or within the **cache** component. it depends on how you did declare it. see if if you find answer in [this other SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592402/yii2-redis-as-database/41595905#41595905).